# how to use zlp2 for installing a module in odoo9

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

i want to install module printer_zpl2 but it shows the error "NameError: name 'zpl2' is not defined" .

My question is how to get or download or install "zpl2" ??
i have executed the command "pip install zpl2" but nothing change . Any help please

Comment: can you see my answer? if you dont need it why you post that post?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install zpl2 with PIP::

```
pip install simple_zpl2
```

or download it using git clone:

```
git clone git://github.com/sacherjj/simple_zpl2
```

or download it using curl:

```
curl -OL https://github.com/sacherjj/simple_zpl2/tarball/master
```

Comment: thanks ,i have installed simple_zpl2 but it always show the same error

Comment: so its an problem on your machine , or in your python environemeent , did you tryed pip installl zpl2?

Comment: yes and it's successfully installed and i'm using python 2.7.13 version . should i restart my PC after installation ??

Comment: @Dhouha , I am using Python 2.7.14, i tryed To PIP Install simple_zpl2 and it worked fine with me , I Think Its a problem on your python or  on your machine

Comment: the probleme is the directory zpl2 exist in my computer with "zpl2.py" and "__init__.py" but it seems that during the installation it doesn't see it . Do you know why ??

Comment: @Dhouha , the Packge must be on C:/Python27/Lib/site-packages/zpl2.py , and you , where you found the package?

Comment: C:\Python2.7.13\Lib\site-packages\zpl2\zpl2.py and C:\Python2.7.13\Lib\site-packages\zpl2.py i have two

Comment: @Dhouha , delete C:/Python2.7.13/Lib/site-packages/zpl2 Folder , and reinstall the module again

Comment: @Dhouha its a problem on your machine not on the script or on the python language

Comment: ok i will try this on another pc . Thnaks . Do you know how to install "CUPS" in windows cuse i have tired to install it "pip  install cups" it shows error . Here is the error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50251470/how-to-install-cups-in-windows-using-python-2-7-13

Comment: @Dhouha i think you need to pip install setuptools or Install tokenize